# Appendix-only table of contents in Revtex

Tags: table-of-contents, revtex, appendix

I am working with the Revtex document style, and would like to add a table of contents to the beginning of my appendix which excludes reference to the main text sections. How can I go about doing this? Some solutions I've seen use the `scrartcl` document class and do not work in my case; I am using `\documentclass[aps,prx,reprint,showpacs,floatfix,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}`.

Note that I do not want to include a table of contents at the beginning of the main text, I only want a table of contents at the start of the appendix, showing only the sections/subsections contained in the appendices.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: There's more than one revtex document class out there. Please do tell us which one you employ. Pleaase also tell us whether or not your document features a table of contents for the main part of the document as well.

Comment: I'm using \documentclass[aps,prx,reprint,showpacs,floatfix,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}, and I do not want a table of contents at the beginning of the main text, just a table of contents at the beginning of the appendix showing only the appendix content.

Comment: @Mensch @Mico do you know how to solve this now that it has been clarified what the document class is and that there's no ToC for the main text? I was about to ask the same question. (In my case it's `\documentclass[reprint, pre, aps]{revtex4-2}`, but I suppose (hope) that the solution is the same as for revtex4-1 from the OP; in both cases there's no toc for the main document.)

Comment: PS. the package ``etoc``, which provides such local ToCs, loads the package ``multicol``, which does not seem to be compatible with ``revtex``.